# How to create a user profile based on uid and navigate to the profile page?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-navigation

I created a user with firebase authentication, also it has its own database.[image: Like this]

The user can send friend requests to other users, the senders uid is saved in the receiver user's request collection. In my app I can list the requests.

[image: requests]

So I have the user’s uid and when I press the eye icon I want to navigate to another page where will be the user’s profile. So I need something like UserProfilePage class. Here’s my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auths/pages/profilepage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auths/services/authentications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auths/main.dart';


class RequestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;

  RequestPage({Key key, @required this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RequestPageState createState() => _RequestPageState(uid);
}

class _RequestPageState extends State<RequestPage> {
  final String uid;
  _RequestPageState(this.uid);

  var taskcollections = Firestore.instance.collection('users');
  String task;


  void acceptFriendRequest(String theUid) async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(uid)
        .collection('friendships')
        .document()
        .setData({
      'FriendUid': theUid,
    }).then((onValue) {
      print('current user: ');
      print(uid);
      print(theUid);
    });

    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(theUid)
        .collection('friendships')
        .document()
        .setData({
      'FriendUid': uid,
    }).then((onValue) {
    });

    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(uid)
        .collection('requests')
        .document(theUid)
        .delete();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {  },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Requests",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "tepeno",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            onPressed: () => signOutUser().then((value) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: taskcollections
            .document(uid)
            .collection('requests')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      ds['FriendUid'] ?? '',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "tepeno",
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: Wrap(
                      spacing: 7, // space between two icons
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.check,
                            size: 27.0,
                            color: Colors.brown[900],
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            acceptFriendRequest(ds['FriendUid']);
                          },
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.do_not_disturb,
                            size: 27.0,
                            color: Colors.brown[900],
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //   _onDeleteItemPressed(index);
                          },
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.remove_red_eye,
                            size: 27.0,
                            color: Colors.brown[900],
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {


                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I’m a beginner in Flutter. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do another query, since queries in Firestore are shallow, meaning if you are pointing to the collection `requests`, you won't get the details inside the collection `users`. So you have to get the user details and then send them to the `UserProfilePage` page:

```
onPressed: () async {
  DocumentSnapshot result =  await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).get();
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfilePage(userInfo : result)),
  );
},
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my UserProfilePage how can I output the details in a widget?

Comment: You can use a listview widget or a row widget with text.. basically `userInfo` is of type `DocumentSnapshot` so to get the details you can do `Text(userInfo.data["email"].toString())`

Comment: But instead of Text(userInfo.data["email"].toString()) I called  Text(widget.userInfo["email"].toString())

Comment: Also, is it possible to view in request list the user's username instead of uid? Later I want to have a facebook like ui when it comes to friend requests. So the user's profile picture and name should be displayed.

Comment: It is possible but as I said the queries are shallow so if you want the username then you need to reference collection `user` or (I'm not sure how ur sturcutre it) but you can add the username inside the `request` collection since you are referencing it already

Comment: oh well yes you are right, I can add it to request, but when I want to show the profile picture, it can change over time.

Comment: The profile pic of the user should be inside the user collection